# How to redirect all pages only to index.html using htaccess file and not redirect the image files

Tags: image, .htaccess

How to redirect all pages (pages only) to index.html using htaccess file and not redirect the image files. For some reason I am using this code and an image file on the index.html page isn't showing up.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$
RewriteRule .* /index.html [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 108):

Try this code :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$
RewriteRule .* /index.html [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Your second condition should escape the dot as well `!\.(gif ...`. Otherwise this could stop a match on a directory ending with these characters. Consider using `[NC]` as well.

Comment: Just what I tried to ask on webmaster. Thanks! I changed the 302 to 301 and was in business :) I now just need to also redirect all images not in a folder in the root. So /img/*gif|jpg|png should be left alone but /subfolderNotImg|Js|Css should redirect

Comment: Actually it seems I should use 410 Gone instead of redirection

Comment: You might want to add svg|map|woff2|woff|ttf. For loading svg images, map files and webfonts.

Comment: Could you provide an universal solution that would work with apache alias? actually `www.example.com/projects/awesome.html` redirects to `www.example.com/index.html` instead of `www.example.com/projects/index.html`

Answer (score 19):

Keep your rules simple. Instead of filtering what shouldn't match, just match on the files.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$
RewriteRule .*\.(php|html)$ /index.html [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 12):

A nicer way might be just to ignore existing files. For example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* / [L,R=302]
```

The `!-d` says to ignore the rewrite if there is an existing directory that meets the match.

The `!-f` says to ignore the rewrite if there is an existing file that meets the match.

Everything else will get rewritten.

Comment: I've tried every-thing to make this work.  This is the first that did it.  Thank you very much.

Comment: I needed to redirect EVERYthing to a temporary "under construction" page... this worked.  (Minus the lines with the `!-d`/`!-f`, of course.)  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add a `.htaccess` file inside the `public` directory, so whenever you build your app, it automatically gets copied to the new `dist` directory. The content of`.htaccess` should be like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following before the last line

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp)$
```

Comment: +1 but you could bring the `.` out as `!\.(png|jpe?g|gif|bmp)$ [NC]`