# Rewrite url htaccess apache angularjs

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess

I am working for the first time with

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
    });
```

set to true, so i know i need to create a .htacces file to redirect for reloading purpose. Found many threads here but non of them seem to work for me.
I am quite depressed..

I am using:

- Angular 1.5.7
- Apache
- SimpleHttpServer on Mac for local testing

In my .htacces I tried to use something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

I always get a 404 when refreshing the page.
Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: I will need more information on this. But before that could you try following solutions.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709500/how-to-redirect-all-pages-only-to-index-html-using-htaccess-file-and-not-redirec

Comment: Didn't work. What infos do you need? @sanjaypatel